# React useRef current value fired twice when assigned within useState callback

Tags: reactjs, use-ref

## Problem

When the button is clicked, the output of the ref current value is skipped. Please refer to the output below for reference. However if the `toggle.current = current + 1` is outside of the useState callback, it worked as accordingly.

## Code

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [array, setArray] = useState(["a"]);
  const toggle = useRef(1);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setArray((a) => {
      let current = toggle.current;
      console.log(current);
      toggle.current = current + 1;
      return [...a, "a"];
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={() => handleChange()}>hi</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

## Desired Output

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

## Actual Output

```
1
2
4
6
8
```

Answer (score 5):

You must be using [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html).

`StrictMode` will intentionally **double invoke** "render" and some other lifecycle methods to [detect side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects). Strict mode checks are run in development mode only; they do not impact the production build.

Here is a [code snippet / demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199206/2873538).