# useMemo vs. useCallback in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to understand the difference between useMemo and useCallback and this statement in the documentation "useCallback(fn, deps) is equivalent to useMemo(() => fn, deps)."

So in useMemo, I have to pass a function that returns a function?  In useCallback, I simply return a function.  I get useCallback, but I am not sure about useMemo and this function that returns a function (or do I have this all wrong).  Reading the SO posts is not helping here quite yet.

If useMemo is calling a function that returns a function, when is the second function called in react?

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66626493/2873538)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to memoize a function you will use `useCallback`, syntax: `useCallback(fn, deps)`.
But if you want to memoize the return ***value*** of the function then you should use `useMemo`, syntax: `useMemo(() => fn(), deps)`

Now If I compare two syntaxes in the following statement

> `useCallback(fn, deps)` is equivalent to `useMemo(() => fn, deps)`

Here for `useMemo` you're not invoking `fn` so you get that function itself not the return value of it. In this case both `useCallback(fn, deps)` and `useMemo(() => fn, deps)` give you the memoized `fn`.

Answer (score 0):

### useMemo

Return a memorized value.
Means it gives you referential equity for value.

### useCallback

Return a memorized callback.
Means it gives you referential equity for functions.