# Render Once for Multiple set States using useState hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-component

Is there a way to refresh / render a function component once after updating multiple states?

For example:

```
const [first, setFirst] = useState(false);
const [second, setSecond] = useState(false);
```

when called ...

```
...
setFirst(true);
setSecond(true);
```

... then the component will refresh twice. Is it possible to set both and refresh (or render) only once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use your states as an object and set them in one instead of separete states like

```
const [exampleState, setExampleState] = useState(
  {fields: {
        fieldOne: false,
        fieldTwo: false
        }
   })
```

You can set in this way

```
    setExampleState({...exampleState, fields: {
        fieldOne: true,
        fieldTwo: true
        },
   })
```

Comment: This is an immediate solution I completely forgot about +1.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see it rendering twice. It is rendering exactly once because both set states are getting **batched** together.

```js
function App() {

  const [first, setFirst] = React.useState(false);
  const [second, setSecond] = React.useState(false);
  const counter = React.useRef(1)
  
  console.log('rendering: ', counter.current++)
 
  return (
    <button onClick={() => {
      setFirst(p => !p)
      setSecond(p => !p)
    }}>{first?'t1':'f1'}, {second?'t2':'f2'}</button>)
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('mydiv'))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
</body>
```

Maybe, you are seeing it rendering twice as a result of using [StrictMode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html). `StrictMode` will intentionally double invoke "render" and some other lifecycle methods to detect [side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

See [Why is React Component render counter getting incremented by 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66199206/2873538) for a demo.

---

#### Update:

I think you are looking for a solution mentioned in @EvrenK's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66445743/2873538) i.e. **Merge your state variables**.

Normally, in most cases, you don't have to worry too much about **rerenders** unless it becomes an apparent issue. If and when it becomes noticeable **issue / delay**, you can avoid *renders* caused by change in `props` using `Reat.memo`.

There is no way, you can avoid renders caused by change in `states`.

However, there is a **hacky** way to have more control of your renders: *Move all (those few causing the issue) data from state to `ref` / `useRef`* and create **one state data** to trigger the final render.

Example:

```
const data1 = useRef()
const data2 = useRef()
const data3 = useRef()
const [renderD1D2D3, setRenderD1D2D3] = useState(false)

function handleChange1(newValue) {
  data1.current = newValue // Won't trigger render
}
function handleChange2(newValue) {
  data2.current = newValue // Won't trigger render
}
function handleChange3(newValue) {
  data3.current = newValue // Won't trigger render
}

function allGoodLetsRenderNow() {
  setRenderD1D2D3(prev => !prev) // Would trigger render
}

return (
  <>
    <div>{data1.current}</div>
    <div>{data2.current}</div>
    <div>{data3.current}</div>
  </>
)
```

Comment: This was helpful, although not necessarily answering the query. If you could propose a solution without turning off StrictMode then I'll accept the answer. +1